# Setting up MarkLogic 5 Express on Windows 7 Professional

Tags: marklogic

I have set up MarkLogic on my Win 7 Professional laptop. I indexed about 2K documents, used the transform filter for PDF documents. I can see the documents in the "`docbase`" when I look via the `XQuery` console.  Everything seems 'OK' except that when I search for a word that I know is in many of the documents, I get no results. When I search for "`null`" (no keyword at all) I get the right number of results, each with an `Internal Server Error 500` (which isn't explained anywhere).

Is there some simple step during or after Loading & Transforming documents, building a flow, and "deploying" that I am missing?  Everything seems 'OK' except --the most important part-- search doesn't find anything.

Comment: Can you please provide the code  you are using to search? Also, that exactly are you doing that is causing the 500 error? Can you provide the text of the error as well?

Comment: I am trying to search via the deployed search panel, not via "code." each error for the "null" search above is simply "Error: 500 Internal Server Error. More information is available in the server's error log." I do not see that error in the server log.  One thing occurs to me: None of this content is XML; it is all standard office formats, predominately PDF.  Should I create a search form for such content? I assumed "transformation" would take care of that.

Comment: And here is the code in my xQuery, which yields nothing but I know there are many matches: xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace search =
"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";
search:search("ECM")

Comment: One last point, Clark: I attended a recent Intro to ML Workshop.  Got through the sample XML exercise.  Here I am working with only unstructured data and want to see ML search just that, as a comparison with Lucene, Endeca, etc.  After I get this simple app working, I'll expand it... Thanks in advance. Bob

Comment: What did you do in the "transformation" step? Can you try clearing your database and loading a simple xml file and re-running your query?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to try to reproduce this issue after so long, but this seems to work just fine for me on MarkLogic 6.0-1.1:

- create a flow with a filesystem collector pointing to a directory with some PDFs
- add a filter transform which is marked to store extracted info as separate `XHTML`
- run the flow
- create a new app builder app pointing to the database in which the documents have been loaded
- deploy the app with a unique name and on a free port number
- open the search app in a browser, should show first docs immediately
- pick any word from any of the `XHTML` results, and search for it
- should show relevant results

Note: Make sure you either type the word in `all-lower-caps` or in exactly `matching-caps`. If you use caps in your search term, MarkLogic will use `case-sensitive` search.